# why can't I assign object variables within the try block?

Tags: c#, try-catch-finally

Why can't I assign object variables within the `try` block?

If I attempt to do this and clean up the variable in the `finally` block I get a compiler error: *"use of unassigned local variable"*.   This makes no sense because the variable is declared before the `try` block, and in the `finally` block I am first checking whether the variable is `null`.

Why can't the following code compile?  I am checking whether `dbc` is `null` so there's no chance of it trying to do something with an unassigned variable.

eg:

```
DbConnection dbc;
try {
    dbc = <some method call returning an open DbConnection>
    // do stuff
} catch (Exception e) { // do stuff }
finally { 
    if (dbc != null) {
        dbc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about removing the Set keyword?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94977/why-arent-variables-declared-in-try-in-scope-in-catch-or-finally

Comment: I bet Jon Skeet will show up from nowhere and get the best answer award. Yawn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your declaration to `DbConnection dbc = null;` so the compiler can know for certain that the variable is assigned. (Merely *declaring* `dbc` is not the same as assigning it a value of null, you must be explicit with a local.)

The reason your existing code fails is that it is entirely possible for an exception to occur before dbc is set. As such, the compiler cannot assume that dbc is assigned by the time the finally block executes.

For more info, see section 5.3 of the language specification on definite assignment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Surely the variable is null if it is not assigned?

Comment: @Craig, no, the variable is merely unassigned. `null` does not constitute the lack of assignment.

Comment: Is this peculiar to C#? I don't remember this in any other language.

Comment: Global and member variables get auto-nulled, I believe. Local variables do not ... for efficiency purposes. Don't quote me on this one, look it up.

Comment: @Craig: Javascript behaves the same way: `null` and `undefined` [mean two slightly different things](http://joeyjavas.com/2007/04/25/javascript-difference-between-null-and-undefined/).

Comment: Just like VB.NET, C# also automatically nulls local variables.  However, unlike VB.NET, the C# compiler thinks you probably made a mistake by having a path through your code that never initializes it.  That catches a *lot* of bugs.

Comment: In my case I return in the exception handler, so surely the compiler should know then that it's kind of irrelevant that it's unassigned as if it wasn't assigned the code referencing it will never be executed?

Comment: @deed02392, might need to see a code sample to be sure what you're talking about. But the general rule is that if you assign only in the `try`, code in a `catch`, `finally`, or afterwards cannot know for sure that the variable was assigned and it will be a compiler error to try to use it before an assignment occurs.

Comment: Ah that's right, I had added conditions that didn't handle every exception so that some exceptions would proceed to let it be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
DbConnection dbc;
```

to this

```
DbConnection dbc = null;
```