# Java Neo4j Transaction: how can I access transaction declared in try-header in catch blocks?

Tags: java, exception, neo4j, scope, try-catch

I have this:

```
try(Transaction t = sess.beginTransaction()){
           // do something with t...

} catch (Exception e) {  // abort transaction if something goes wrong
            ...
           t.rollback();
           t.close();
}
```

However, *t* is not in scope of the catch block. I reviewed this here [try/catch scope in Java/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94977/why-arent-variables-declared-in-try-in-scope-in-catch-or-finally).

Declaring t before the try-catch-block doesn´t work, as the syntax in *try* requires the variable to be declared right there.

Is there any way that I can initialize *t* like this, and still make sure that the transaction gets closed / rollbacked? Or should I just begin the transaction before the try/catch-block?

EDIT: Transaction is an 'AutoClosable'. Does this mean I don't need to explicitly handle rollback and closing?

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize Transaction t as default before the try, it might work

Comment: I did it, but I wanted to make use of the 'auto closing' with this syntax

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> *"how can I access transaction declared in try-header in catch blocks?"*

You can't. Using "try-with-resources" is convenient in many scenarios, but not intended to allow accessing the underlying resource (database transaction) within the `try` block.

Instead, if you want to have direct control over the resource, you would need to do code like below. It's different from your approach in that it isn't using the automatic "try-with-resources" statement. Also, note that the `t.close()` is in the `finally` block (not the `catch` block) - you should always try to close the transaction, whether or not an exception was thrown.

```
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
try {
    t.run("...");
    t.commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
    t.rollback();

} finally {
    t.close();
}
```

Further, according to docs, if your `catch` block were to run in your try-with-resources attempt, the resource (your transaction) would have already been closed *prior* to running the code in the catch block:

> *In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed.*

Above is from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html, which includes other detail and examples.